# HackerRank Python Compilation Error in Void Function: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘while’ OR unused variable

Tags: python, while-loop, compiler-errors, void

The goal of the exercise is to print a list of numbers from 1 to n, but if the number is divisible by 3, 5, or both 3 & 5, you print out "Fizz", "Buzz", or "Fizzbuzz" respectively.  I've never used a void function before, and keep getting an errors to these effects:

1. expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘while’
   while count <= n:
2. warning: unused variable ‘count’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int count = 1

Please advise:

```
void fizzBuzz(int n) {
    int count = 1
    while count <= n:
        if count%3==0:
            if count%5 == 0:
                print("Fizzbuzz")
            else:
                print("Fizz")
        if count%5==0:
            print("Buzz")
        else:
            print(n)
        count+=1
}
```

Comment: What language are you even using? The first two lines are from a C-like language, but the rest seems legit python. `int count = 1` is invalid syntax in python and you should get an error for that. But I would never expect to see an error like #1 in python.  The error implies that the language expected is actually something like C, and the first transgression is that you missed a semi-colon in the line `int count = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

python doesn't have void as a function definition, try changing `void fizzBuzz(int n) {` to `def fizzBuzz(n):`. You also do not need to define count with the datatype int because Python automatically takes care of the type. Also defining functions in python uses a colon just like the while loop and everything inside the function has to be indented. One last note. By printing n at the end you are just printing the limit you're counting to. Change that to `print(count)` and the fizzBuzz function will work as intended.